# IIS Manager is showing empty list

Tags: iis

I'm using Windows 10 and IIS Manager 10,
I've enabled all the features in **Program and Features** but still, I don't find anything under IIS Manager.

> *Screenshot attached*
> [image]

Comment: Windows 10 Home edition?

Comment: You can try to use the "appcmd.exe list sites" and "appcmd.exe list apppools" commands in cmd to check the status of IIS sites and application pools.

Comment: You can also try to restart IIS by running the iisreset command in cmd.

Comment: @Lex Li I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @DingPeng I've run cmd as Administrator and run the command `iisreset /restart` but it gives me an error.

`Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to use this
command. Either have your account added to the administrator local group of
the remote computer or to the domain administrator global group.`

Comment: `iisreset /status` showing


`Status for IIS Admin Service ( IISADMIN ) : Running`
`Status for Windows Process Activation Service ( WAS ) : Running`
`Status for Net.Msmq Listener Adapter ( NetMsmqActivator ) : Running`
`Status for Net.Pipe Listener Adapter ( NetPipeActivator ) : Start pending`
`Status for Net.Tcp Listener Adapter ( NetTcpActivator ) : Start pending`
`Status for World Wide Web Publishing Service ( W3SVC ) : Running`

Checked the services.svc and these two services **Net.Tcp** and **Net.Pipe** are stuck at *Stating*. No options to stop or restart here.

Comment: @DingPeng `appcmd.exe list sites` and `appcmd.exe list apppools` returns empty

Comment: I suspect that you may not successfully install IIS, you can refer to this link to learn how to install IIS in Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7

Comment: Hi,has the problem been solved?

Comment: Problem not resolved yet.

Comment: Did you install IIS with the steps in the installation link? If you have followed the correct steps and installde IIS but still did not solve the problem, I suspect this may be caused by the operating system, I suggest you repair or upgrade your operating system.